# ggplot2 doesn't show Chinese character properly in rstudio-server in docker

Tags: r, docker, ggplot2, rstudio-server

I try to use ggplot2 to plot a chart with the Chinese title but shows Unicode in a square.

I've tried some following command

```
quartz(family='STKaiti')
par(family='STKaiti')
plot(1, xlab = "你好", family = "Heiti SC Light")
```

and use "extrafont" font to load my ubuntu fonts into R
[image]
The characters plot shows are still Unicode in a square. I want to show the Chinese word properly.

Still, I have no idea how to call this kind of words. "Unicode in a square" is the best I can describe.

Answer (score 7):

Try the [`showtext`](https://github.com/yixuan/showtext) package, which was designed for this.

Sample code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(showtext)
showtext_auto()

p = ggplot(NULL, aes(x = 1, y = 1)) + ylim(0.8, 1.2) +
    annotate("text", 1, 1, size = 15, label = "你好，世界") +
    xlab("坐标轴") +
    theme_bw(base_family = "wqy-microhei", base_size = 24)

quartz()
print(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I get the Chinese words printed perfectly!