# strange symbols generated from rmarkdown when I use Chinese characters in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, bookdown

Recently, I encounter a problem in Rmarkdown.
When I add Chinese characters into `xlab()` and `ylab()` in ggplot2. The pdf document generated by rmd will display strange `......` symbol. However, I try to search useful  something and the result told me I should add `dev: cairo_pdf`. Ok, after I add the code to `YAML`, the new error strange symbols occur again. It displays another strange symbols of `□□□`.

[image]

[image]
I want to ask for help from someone who may pay attention to my quesiton. Could you help me?  Thank you very much. And here my test code:

```
---
title: "test.Rmd"
author: "author"
documentclass: ctexart
output:
  rticles::ctex:
    fig_caption: yes
    number_sections: yes
    toc: no
    dev: cairo_pdf
  word_document: default
keywords:
header-includes: \usepackage{booktabs} \usepackage{longtable} \usepackage{array} \usepackage{multirow}
  \usepackage{wrapfig} \usepackage{float} \floatplacement{figure}{H}
---
```

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(cars,aes(speed,dist)) + 
  geom_line()+xlab("速度\nSpeed") + ylab("距离\nDist")
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I cannot replicate your images. I just altered the `header-includes` and included the figure in a code chunk. Did you install `xelatex` and `TeX Live`?

Here is the code that worked fine for me:

````
---
title: "test.Rmd"
author: "author"
documentclass: ctexart
output:
  rticles::ctex:
    fig_caption: yes
    number_sections: yes
    toc: no
    dev: cairo_pdf
  word_document: default
header-includes: 
  - \usepackage{booktabs} 
  - \usepackage{longtable} 
  - \usepackage{array} 
  - \usepackage{multirow}
  - \usepackage{wrapfig} 
  - \usepackage{float} 
  - \floatplacement{figure}{H}  
---

```{r}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(cars,aes(speed,dist)) + 
  geom_line()+xlab("速度\nSpeed") + ylab("距离\nDist")
```
````

-output

[image]

Comment: I've no idea. I copy your code completely, but it is still the same thing for me. It shows the symbol `□□`. But when I copy the `□□` , it shows the correct Chinese characters "速度".

Comment: Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55875250/13249862), try to add `library(showtext)` and `showtext_auto()`.